# Python Counter like matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, counter

```
for a in range(99):
    for b in range(99):
        for c in range(99):
            for d in range(99):
                for e in range(99):
                    for f in range(99):
                        for g in range(99):
                            for h in range(99):
                                for i in range(99):
                                    for j in range(99):
                                        for k in range(99):
                             sayi=str(k)+str(j)+str(i)+str(h)+str(g)+str(f)+str(e)+str(d)+str(c)+str(a)+str(b)
print(sayi)
```

While the leftmost numbers count from 1 to 9, I want it to go backwards from the number 9 at the same time, but I couldn't get out of it with this for loop.

same time

```
a b c
1 9 1
2 8 2
3 7 3
4 6 4
5 5 5
6 4 6
7 3 7
8 2 8
9 1 9
```

a count 1-9, b countdown 9-1 c count 1-9 some time

Comment: Please make your code readable.

Comment: I still cannot understand your question fully. Can you provide a clear example of the output? I already generated your first example in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're looking for a simultaneous loop over multiple variables. For this you should use `zip` and follow this syntax:

```
for a,b,c in zip(range(1,10),range(9,0,-1),range(1,10)): # One range for each variable
    sayi = f'{a} {b} {c}'  # Equivalent of sayi = str(a)+' '+str(b)+' '+str(c)
    print(sayi)

#    1 9 1
#    2 8 2
#    3 7 3
#    4 6 4
#    5 5 5
#    6 4 6
#    7 3 7
#    8 2 8
#    9 1 9
```

If you really want to keep each loop independent, try modifying the parameters of the `range` function in each `for` loop:

```
for a in range(10):
    for b in range(9,-1,-1):
        for c in range(10): # One range and 'for loop' per variable
            sayi = f'{a} {b} {c}'  # Equivalent of sayi = str(a)+' '+str(b)+' '+str(c)
            print(sayi)

# 0 9 0
# 0 9 1
# 0 9 2
# 0 9 3
# 0 9 4
# 0 9 5
# 0 9 6
# 0 9 7
# 0 9 8
# 0 9 9
# 0 8 0
# 0 8 1
# 0 8 2
# 0 8 3
# ...
```

Comment: Yes ı want it but no convert to int, ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 9 1'

Comment: ibarrond very thanks I converted int :) 
Well, can we make each of these separate columns independent of each other,

Comment: and always in loop if 0 and restart or if 9 and restart each loop

Comment: I'm not sure about what you're asking. If you show me your expected result in the question (including the type), I can provide you the code to generate it.

Comment: I sent to you email, sorry this, but I cannt attach the pict. here

Comment: I resent you an email

Comment: Please use Stack Overflow and avoid private messages. The community will only benefit if you do so. You can add images to the question directly in Stack Overflow.

Comment: yes but I cannt add picture or video

Comment: it need  reputation

Comment: http://konasotomotiv.com/count.jpg

Comment: http://konasotomotiv.com/1.mp4

Comment: its impossible ? in python?